# object distribution implementation (observer between remote machine)

Tags: c#

I writing application that contain a server and 10 remote client.
The clients contain UI and the server need to do distribution of objects to all the clients (sending byte[]) that will show all the objects on the UI 
( kind of observer between remote machine ).

I looking for some good way to do the object distribution from the server to all the clients.

I can keep all the ip address in table and send each client. 
I also can do it using multicast distribution.

But i wander if there any better way.

Comment: Maybe have a look at SignalR

Comment: i know signalR - but this think this is over kill for what i trying to do

Comment: If the application is not too complex you could try .NET remoting (i.e. `MarshalByRefObject`), example here: http://aviadezra.blogspot.de/2008/06/code-snippets-remoting-client-server_19.html  Another option would be WCF (it also supports duplex communication): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that both technologies are a bit outdated.

Comment: .net remoting is legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e7z38xb(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: check the singleR - this is not fit for what i need - this is using for web and my clients are not web